# Proving $\forall n \in N, \exists p \in N$, $p>n$ $\wedge$ $(prime(p) \wedge p \equiv 2\pmod3)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove that $\forall n \in N, \exists p \in N$, $p>n$ $\wedge$ $(prime(p) \wedge p = 2mod3)$ using the definitions below:

[image]

I genuinely have no idea where to start and how to go about this proof.

I would really appreciate it if someone could explain to how prove the statement.

Comment: oh I think you're right I misread the initial problem

Comment: Consider the prime factors of $3(n!)-1.$ Show that at least one of them is $\equiv 2\pmod 3.$

Comment: This is a particular case of [Dirichlet's Theorem for Primes in Arithmetic Progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions).

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $5 + 6n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407259/how-do-you-prove-that-there-are-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-5-6n)