# Prove that there are infinitely many primes $P_i\equiv1\pmod6$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Proving that there are infinitely many primes is fairly simple:

- Assume that there is a finite number of primes.
- Let $G$ be the set of **all** primes $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_n$.
- Compute $K = P_1 \times P_2 \times \cdots \times P_n + 1$.
- If $K$ is prime, then it is obviously **not** in $G$.
- Otherwise, **none** of its prime factors are in $G$.
- Conclusion: $G$ is **not** the set of **all** primes.

I thought I could use a similar method in order to prove:

- There are infinitely many primes $P_i\equiv1\pmod6$
- There are infinitely many primes $P_i\equiv5\pmod6$

But it doesn't appear to be that simple... any ideas?

Comment: Well, for simplicity, if $P_i\equiv 1\pmod 6$ and $P_i\equiv 5\pmod 6$ then $P_i\equiv \pm 1\pmod 6$.

Answer (score 5):

The case of $5$ is easy: an integer $\equiv 5 \bmod 6$ must be divisible by at least one prime $\equiv 5 \bmod 6$.
I don't think the case of $1$ is so simple.  In general, Dirichlet's theorem is not trivial.

Comment: There is a simple method for $1$. See my hint.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but how do you prove that there isn't a finite amount of such primes that divide all those integers?

Comment: If there are only finitely many primes $p_1, \ldots, p_n \equiv 5 \mod 6$, consider $K = p_1 \ldots p_n + 6$ (if $n$ is odd) or $p_1^2 \ldots p_n + 6$ (if $n$ is even).
Then $K \equiv 5 \mod 6$, and is not divisible by any of $p_1, \ldots, p_n$.

Comment: Easier to just do $6p_1p_2\dots p_n+5$, @RobertIsrael

Comment: Or rather $6p_1p_2\dots p_n-1$, I suppose $6p_1\dots p_n+5$ could be a power of $5$. :)

Answer (score 5):

There is an old argument (don't know the correct attribution) to prove that there are infinitely-many primes $=1 \mod N$: let $f$ be the $N$-th cyclotomic polynomial. Note that $p\mid f(n)$ implies that $n$ is a primitive $N$-th root of unity mod $p$, so $p=1\bmod N$. Given a finite collection $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ of primes $=1$ mod $N$, for sufficiently large integer $\ell$, $f(\ell\cdot p_1\ldots p_k)>1$, so has some prime factor...

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $-3$ is a square modulo a prime $p>3$ if and only if $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$.

So any number of the form $X^2+3$ with $X$ even and relatively prime to $3$ is only divisibly by primes $p$ of the form $6k+1$.

Comment: Probably a silly question, but how do you prove that there isn't a finite amount of such primes that divide all those numbers?

Comment: That's why it was a hint. Given a finite number of such primes, pick $X$ carefully, similar to Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes.

Answer (score 0):

If we cross out from sequence of positive integers all numbers divisible by $2$ and all numbers divisible by $3$, then all remaining numbers will be in one of two forms:

$S1(n)=6n−1=5,11,17,...$ or $S2(n)=6n+1=7,13,19,....n=1,2,3,...$ So all prime numbers also will be in one of these two forms and ratio 0f number of primes in the sequence $S1(n)$ to number of primes in the sequence $S2(n)$ tends to be $1$.

Comment: This shows that $S1(n) \cup S2(n)$ is infinite but does not show that $S2(n)$ is infinite.

Comment: Please see [link](_https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3037819/the-prime-number-matrix-sieve_)

Comment: see [link](_https://www.academia.edu/13890086/Matrix_sieve_the_easiest_way_to_find_prime_numbers_)

Comment: Daniel Wainfleet  Since ratio of number of primes in the sequence$S1(n)$to number of primes in the sequence $S2(n)$ tends to be 1, so numbers  of primes in both these sequences are infinite

Comment: For explanation  of the ratio  of number of primes in the sequence$S1(n)$to number of primes in the sequence $S2(n)$ see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185260/is-the-number-of-primes-congruent-to-1-mod-6-equal-to-the-number-of-primes-congr/3155638#3155638