# The prime number matrix sieve

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have derived the following theorem:

An odd positive integer $N=6n−1$ is a prime iff neither of two diophantine equations

$6x^2+(6x−1)y=n$

$6x^2+(6x+1)y=n$

has solution.

An odd positive integer $N=6n+1$ is a prime iff neither of two diophantine equations

$6x^2−2x+(6x−1)y=n$

$6x^2+2x+(6x+1)y=n$

has solution.

$x=1,2,3,\ldots;y=0,1,2,\ldots;n=1,2,3,\ldots$

Theorem allows to substitute the task: "Find all primes in the range $(N_1;N_2)$"  by the task: "Find positive integers which do not appear in the range $(n_1;n_2)$ in two pairs of $2$-dimensional arrays

$P_1(i,j)=6i^2+(6i-1)(j-1)$

$P_2(i,j)=6i^2+(6i+1)(j-1)$

$i,j = 1,2,3,\ldots$

for primes in the sequence $N=6n-1$.

$P_3(i,j)=6i^2-2i+(6i-1)(j-1)$

$P_4(i,j)=6i^2+2i+(6i+1)(j-1)$

$i,j = 1,2,3,\ldots$

for primes in the sequence $N=6n+1$.
 Since all primes (except $2$ and $3$) are in one of two forms $6n−1$ or $6n+1$.

Can anybody advice me - is proposed "matrix sieve" algorithm well known?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Crossposted on MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317604/the-prime-number-matrix-sieve

Comment: Consider posting your derivation and asking if it is correct.

Comment: See [link] (_http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/BrowseCategoryOrSearchResults.asp?lngWId=3&blnAuthorSearch=TRUE&lngAuthorId=21687209&strAuthorName=Boris%20Sklyar&txtMaxNumberOfEntriesPerPage=25_)

Comment: See [link] (_https://www.academia.edu/13890086/Matrix_sieve_the_easiest_way_to_find_prime_numbers_)