# For $n \geq 6$, why are the number of prime pairs $(p,q)$ where $p+q=6n$ > $6n+2$ and $6n+4$ pairs?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Noticed a pattern for $n \geq 6$, the number of prime pairs $(p,q)$ where $p+q=6n$, is always greater than the pairs for $6n+2$ and $6n+4$.

For example, when $n=6$

$36$ has $8$ prime pairs

```
(5,31) (7,29) (13,23) (17,19) (19,17) (23,13) (29,7) (31,5)
```

$38$ has $3$ prime pairs

```
(7,31) (19,19) (31,7)
```

$40$ has $6$ prime pairs

```
(3,37) (11,29) (17,23) (23,17) (29,11) (37,3)
```

The charts below show peaks for $6n$ and troughs for $6n+2$ and $6n+4$

[image: primePairs]

This pattern seems to continue indefinitely ...

[image: primePairs10mil]

**Question**

Does this pattern hold true for all $6n$ peaks?

Comment: I think this might have to do with the fact that primes are always 1 or 5 mod 6. If we separate them into 2 categories, we take one from each category to get a sum 6n, but we need to take 2 from 1 category to get 6n+2 or 6n+4.

Comment: Dirichlet tells us that, on average, a prime is equally likely to be either $\pm 1 \pmod 6$.  Thus a randomly selected pair sums to $6n$ with probability $\frac 12$, and to $6n\pm 2$ with probability $\frac 14$ each.

Comment: Here you might find the answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54259/why-are-goldbach-laggards-biased-towards-2-bmod-6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a few commentors have pointed out, a prime is either $1$ or $5$ (mod $6$), and single prime has a ~$50$% of being in either group. Thus, we only need one of each to get a sum of $6n$, but we need two numbers that are equal (mod $6$) to get $6n+2$ or $6n+4$ (only a $25$% chance).

The specifics of your question have likely been worked out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185260/is-the-number-of-primes-congruent-to-1-mod-6-equal-to-the-number-of-primes-congr). You have found a cool visual way to see this!